# Emacs - Autosave buffer every 5 seconds

Tags: emacs, buffer, dot-emacs, emacs24

How can we configure emacs to automatically save the unsaved changes every 5 seconds? I want the save the buffer and not the temporary file generated with ~

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In ~/.emacs file make following changes.

```
(require 'auto-save-buffers)
(run-with-idle-timer 5 t 'auto-save-buffers)
```

Answer (score 1):

change the auto-save-timeout's value affects the number of seconds idle time before auto-save.

using (setq auto-save-timeout 5) may solve your problem